# How can I make AJAX calls to multiple URLs based on button clicks?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have multiple buttons on my page. I want to make an AJAX call to a different URL based on each button and then populate the page with the data. However, I can't get this to work.

```
var variable;

$(".button-1").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "api1.com",
        async: false,
        success: function(result) {
            variable = result;
        }
    });
});

$(".button-2").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "api2.com",
        async: false,
        success: function(result) {
            variable = result;
        }
    });
});

$(".button-3").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "api3.com",
        async: false,
        success: function(result) {
            variable = result;
        }
    });
});

$(".button-4").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "api4.com",
        async: false,
        success: function(result) {
            variable = result;
        }
    });
});


<button class="btn button-1">1</button>
<button class="btn button-2">2</button>
<button class="btn button-3">3</button>
<button class="btn button-4">4</button>
```

Then after the ajax call, I use the object "variable" to populate the rest of the page.

When I dont call ajax with a button click event, my code works perfectly. However, this is only using data from one of the APIs. This is what works:

```
var variable;

$.ajax({
    url: "api1.com",
    async: false,
    success: function(result) {
        variable = result;
    }
});
```

Since the only thing that is changing is the URL, is it possible to have an AJAX call in a loop, making URL a variable based on a button click?

Comment: try to console.log results and see whats happens with each click!

Comment: use `$(document).on('click','.button-1',function(e){` or add your code inside `$(document).ready(function(){})` OR add it before `</body>`

Comment: You should avoid using `async: false` and learn proper Javascript coding.

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/ May be you have to use $.extend to combine the result of each ajax call to the variable object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably doesn't work because whatever code is using the contents of `variable` to render the result has already executed by the time the user presses a button. (from the looks of it)

I'd recommend calling a function to receive that information:

```js
function renderContent(content) {
  $('#content').text(content)
}

$('.btn').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  $.ajax({
    url: 'https://cors.io/?' + $(this).data('url'),
    success: function(result) {
      renderContent(result)
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn" data-url="https://postman-echo.com/get?data=api1">API 1</button>
<button class="btn" data-url="https://postman-echo.com/get?data=api2">API 2</button>
<button class="btn" data-url="https://postman-echo.com/get?data=api3">API 3</button>

<div id="content"></div>
```

**Note:** I'm only using `https://cors.io` and `https://postman-echo.com` to show you real results from APIs. You would use your own API in this case.

Comment: this mostly worked! but now im having other issues. when i click the button and console.log through every step of the function (i.e. right after click, then in the ajax success function), I am receiving the correct url and also the correct object in result.

in the renderContent(variable) function, I am doing a somewhat complicated loop through the json object "variable" and then using .html() to replace the contents of my "#content" div with the items. This should list out all the items in my loop like it used to, but it only shows one item for each api url... do you know why that could be?

Comment: did more testing and i noticed the issue. Weirdly enough, using $("#content").html(...) shows only the one card, yet $(...).appendTo("#content") shows all of the items and works totally fine, except for the whole replacing the content part, which is what I need.

Comment: Well, if you call `.html(...)` for each item in the JSON result, I'd be replacing the content over and over again through the course of the loop. There are two possible solutions: 1) Build the HTML in a variable first, where each loop iteration would add a new item and then `.html(...)` the contents of that variable after the loop is finished or 2) before you start looping, you do `.html('')` to remove everything and then `.append(...)` each item.

Comment: **Note:** `$('#content').children().remove()` would be a more descriptive version of `$('#content').html('')`. Whichever you prefer is fine.

Answer (score -1):

Answer to your second question (Since the only thing that is changing is the URL, is it possible to have an AJAX call in a loop, making URL a variable based on a button click?)

You could set up your buttons to contain the url, and then read it from within a common function:

```
<button data-url='api1.com' class='btn'>1</button>
<button data-url='api2.com' class='btn'>2</button>

$(".btn").click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url: $(this).data('url'),
    async: false,
    success: function(result) {
        variable = result;
    }
  });  
});
```

In regards to your first question (why doesn't it work at all) - the comment by @MuhammadOmerAslam is worth investigating, does your javascript occur in-line *after* the elements are defined, or within document.ready?  If not, it should, or the elements won't exist on the page when the javascript tries to find them.

Comment: Why would this work different from what he's written?

Comment: I understood the question to be "how can I assign these event handlers in a loop because only the url changes" - I have given a possible solution to that (although I used a class instead of a loop).  What did you understand the question to be @Barmar?

Comment: I understood the question to be that the code doesn't work at all when he makes the AJAX calls in the event handlers. It wasn't about how to simplify the coding, it was about getting it to work.

Comment: I appreciate answers to both questions. getting it to work is priority but so is clean, reusable code, so id like to accomplish it in the most straightforward way possible. I'm going to try both solutions that were presented by using a data-url attribute, and see which one works best. also @Barmar , I am a she not a "he" lol